# Updates Disappeared Overnight - What Could Be Cause?

Tags: craft3

I made some updates to various aspects of a Craft CMS site early in December. These updates were in place for over a week, and then overnight disappeared.

One example is I made an update to the site's menu via its template.twig file. That update was in place functioning on 12/10 for 2 weeks, then on 12/24, it was gone. The file I had updated now says last modified 11/28.

I should note that I am new to Craft CMS, and this site was built by another dev. That dev said he did not make any updates that would have caused this issue.

What are the other possibilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that your webhost had server / hard drive issues and rolled back to a previous backup of the site without letting you know.

I've also seen cases of hosting companies doing a bad job of migrating customers between servers behind the scenes and migrating an older version of the site.

Regardless, if the last modified file date is before you last changed it, it's likely the issue is with the filesystem itself and not with Craft.

Comment: Thanks. This actually makes a lot of sense, as the site was down due to hosting issues the previous day.